# error configurar proyecto en eclipse con Jboss, da el siguiente error cuando hago el debug

Tags: eclipse, jboss

> Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s):
>   LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed:
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:8080, **ERROR**   Deployment
>   "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following
>   reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el puerto en el que estás levantando JBoss ya está en uso (Si estás en windows, Skype tiene la mala costumbre de ocuparlo).

Puedes modificar el puerto al que está asociado JBoss para evitar este problema, o parar el proceso que está usando dicho puerto.

Para lo segundo, mediante el comando (en windows)

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

Puedes consultar qué puertos están ocupados por qué procesos (con el PID, puedes buscar tu proceso en el administrador de tareas).

Para lo primero, debes buscar tu puerto en el fichero de configuración (si tiras con la configuración por defecto es el standalone.xml), pero normalmente el propio eclipse te permite cambiar este dato en la configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta es antigua, pero respondo por si a alguien más le pasa....

El error se debe a que el puerto ya se encuentra en uso, para esto debes terminarlo mediante consola de comandos CMD con la siguiente sentencia en Windows:

**`netstat -aon | find "8080"`**

Esto te arrojará el PID del proceso que está utilizando el puerto y con ese dato ejecutas:

**`taskkill -f -pid numero_del_proceso`**

Con esto habrás terminado el proceso que ocupaba el puerto **8080** y podrás ejecutar un nuevo proceso sin que se muestre el error.

*Como recomendación, realizar esto con permisos de administrador*.